# How to get final Solr query hit the Solr server in Grails

Tags: grails, solr, lucene

We are using Grails and Solr i have this in in controller

```
def query = "(type:GOOD OR type:BAD) AND city:${cityName}";
        SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery(query);
        solrQuery.setRows(0)
        solrQuery.setFacet(true);
        solrQuery.addFacetField('locality');
        solrQuery.setFacetLimit(10);
        def server = solrService.getServer('world')
        def queryResponse = server.query(solrQuery);
        return queryResponse.getFacetField('locality');
```

I want to know the final query when `queryResponse.getFacetField('locality');` hits Solr. I want to debug a bug in my project, i need final query for it. I want to print that query in console like

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/query?q=*:*&fl=id,title,series_s,pubyear_i
&sort=pubyear_i desc
 &group=true
 &group.main=true
 &group.field=series_s
 &facet=true
 &facet.field=cat
```

Comment: Can you look at the access logs on the solr server?

Answer (score 0):

SolrQuery extends [org.apache.solr.common.params.ModifiableSolrParams](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/solrj/src/java/org/apache/solr/common/params/ModifiableSolrParams.java), which has a toString method that will show you the query parameters.

So basically you can do :

```
log.debug query
```